# How can I capture the network traffic of Docker Swarm containers using netshoot and network_mode?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-swarm

In the past, we've successfully used [nicolaka/netshoot](https://github.com/nicolaka/netshoot) to capture network traffic of Docker containers run with `docker-compose`:

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: "3.6"
services:
  tcpdump:
    image: nicolaka/netshoot
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    command: tcpdump -i any -w /data/nginx.pcap
    network_mode: service:nginx
    volumes:
      - $PWD/data:/data

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
$ docker-compose up
WARNING: The Docker Engine you're using is running in swarm mode.

Compose does not use swarm mode to deploy services to multiple nodes in a swarm. All containers will be scheduled on the current node.

To deploy your application across the swarm, use `docker stack deploy`.

Creating network "netshoot_default" with the default driver
Creating netshoot_nginx_1 ... done
Creating netshoot_tcpdump_1 ... done
$ curl -s -o /dev/null http://localhost
$ docker-compose down
Stopping netshoot_tcpdump_1 ... done
Stopping netshoot_nginx_1   ... done
Removing netshoot_tcpdump_1 ... done
Removing netshoot_nginx_1   ... done
Removing network netshoot_default
$ tshark -2 -r data/nginx.pcap http
   13   4.760638   172.25.0.1 → 172.25.0.2   HTTP 145 GET / HTTP/1.1
   17   4.760866   172.25.0.2 → 172.25.0.1   HTTP 684 HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (text/html)
$
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work if the containers are started with `docker stack create` because `network_mode` is not supported:

```
$ docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml netshoot
Ignoring unsupported options: network_mode

Creating network netshoot_default
Creating service netshoot_tcpdump
Creating service netshoot_nginx
$ curl -s -o /dev/null http://localhost
$ docker stack rm netshoot
Removing service netshoot_nginx
Removing service netshoot_tcpdump
Removing network netshoot_default
$ tshark -2 -r data/nginx.pcap http
$ tshark -2 -r data/nginx.pcap tcp
      6   4.221820   172.18.0.1 → 172.18.0.2   TCP 80 63798 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65495 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=191764735 TSecr=0 WS=128
$
```

How can we configure our netshoot containers in the docker-compose.yml so they share the network interfaces of other containers even if they are started via `docker stack create`?

Comment: in docker compose you specified : "network_mode: service:nginx" its a typo ? ok no. it works. i didnt know that form.

Comment: if you manage doing it please write a reproducible example as this seems really interesting

Comment: you can provide "network: xxx" on every service to force the network link

Answer (score 2):

from there : https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-tcpdump-inter-service-traffic/23463/4

overlay network traffic in swarm does not go thru docker0 or docker_gwbridge.
There are 2 options:
option 1:
Go inside container and do tcpdump:
nicolaka/netshoot is container with all network debug tools.

```
docker run -ti --net container: <container name/id> nicolaka/netshoot
tcpdump -i <eth0>
```

Option 2:
Go inside network namespace of overlay network and do tcpdump:
First find overlay network id with docker network inspect
Start debug container mounting network namespace:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /var/run/docker/netns:/var/run/docker/netns --privileged=true nicolaka/netshoot
```

All namespaces are listed under:
/var/run/docker/netns

Find your swarm overlay network namespace matching with overlay networkid of previous command.
Then enter into network namespace:

```
nsenter --net=/var/run/docker/netns/ sh
tcpdump -i vxlan0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works for what you are trying to do, but you can still attach to the network namespace of a service container.

Assuming that you have passwordless ssh setup to your docker swarm nodes such that:
`docker -H ssh://user@nodeN container ls` retrieves the container list from one of your docker nodes then:

```
docker service ps --no-trunc service_of_interest
```

will return the ID, Name and Node of each service task. Choose one. then simply run netshoot on the same node:

`docker -H ssh://user@$NODE run --rm -it --network container:$NAME.$ID nicolaka/netshoot`

You can automate this from, say, a Makefile. But putting it in a docker-compose.yml is not going to fly as you need to supply too many dynamically looked up details and invoke docker on the specific node.